# Why does [[[!![]+[]]+[]]+[]][+[]][+[]] evaluate to t?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found out that in JavaScript `[[[!![]+[]]+[]]+[]][+[]][+[]]` evaluate to "t". How is it possible?

I do know that `!![]` evaluates to `true`, however how to you obtain "t" from that?

```js
console.log([[[!![]+[]]+[]]+[]][+[]][+[]]);
```

Comment: Some ASCII weirdness. For example, this `[[[![]+[]]+[]]+[]][-[]][-[]]` evaluates to `f`.

Comment: First letter of "true"

Comment: `[[[!![]+[]]+[]]+[]]` evaluates to `["true"]` and `+[]` evaluates to `0` so `["true"][0][0]` evaluates to `"t"`

Comment: How do you get `["true"]` from `[[[!![]+[]]+[]]+[]]`? Isn't `!![]` a boolean?

Comment: @User12345 `!![]` is `true`. `true + []` is `"true"`. That's how you get `["true"]`.