# How does the input below output as 'fail'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

How does this:

```
(![] + [])[+[]] +
(![] + [])[+!+[]] +
([![]] + [][[]])[+!+[] + [+[]]] +
(![] + [])[!+[] + !+[]];
```

out put as 'fail'?

Comment: See: [Why does ++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\] return the string “10”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157) | [Why does ++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\] return the string “10”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157) | [(!\[\]+\[\])\[+\[\]\]… Explain why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4170978) | [How “NaNundefined”\[10\] =“e” Or (\[+\[\]\[\[\]\]\]+\[\]\[\[\]\])\[++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\]\] = “e”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14646173) | [Why does \[\[\[!!\[\]+\[\]\]+\[\]\]+\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]\[+\[\]\] evaluate to t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46220914)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does ++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\] return the string "10"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-does-return-the-string-10)